# Populate new column with added day to date in another row and and another column based on condition in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've a dateset like this:

| date | Condition |
| --- | --- |
| 20-01-2015 | 1 |
| 20-02-2015 | 1 |
| 20-03-2015 | 2 |
| 20-04-2015 | 2 |
| 20-05-2015 | 2 |
| 20-06-2015 | 1 |
| 20-07-2015 | 1 |
| 20-08-2015 | 2 |
| 20-09-2015 | 2 |
| 20-09-2015 | 1 |

I want a new column date_new which should look at the condition in next column. If condition is one, do nothing. If condition is 2, add a day to the date and store in date_new.
Additional condition- There should be 3 continuous 2's for this to work.

The final output should look like this.

| date | Condition | date_new |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20-01-2015 | 1 |  |
| 20-02-2015 | 1 |  |
| 20-03-2015 | 2 | 21-02-2015 |
| 20-04-2015 | 2 |  |
| 20-05-2015 | 2 |  |
| 20-06-2015 | 1 |  |
| 20-07-2015 | 1 |  |
| 20-08-2015 | 2 |  |
| 20-09-2015 | 2 |  |
| 20-09-2015 | 1 |  |

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What is type of data column, is it str?

Comment: date : datetime64[ns], condition : int64

Comment: @newbie Your final output shows +1 day for condition "1", I guess you made an error?

Comment: @wordinone Column date_new needs a next date of previous '1' condition as long as there are three consecutive 2s in condition. Apologies if I phrased it wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand last msg, can you be more specific?

Comment: @wordinone The new column date_new should check condition, if 1, do nothing. If 2,2,2 (consecutive three 2's) in condition, date_new should add one day to previous 1's date.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I've edited my answer and transform it into a function:

```
def newdate(df):
 L = df.Condition
 res = [i for i, j, k in zip(L, L[1:], L[2:]) if i == j == k]
 if 2 in res:
  df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
  df['new_date'] = df.apply(lambda x: x["date"]+pd.DateOffset(days=2) if x["Condition"]==2 else pd.NA, axis=1)
  df['new_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['new_date'])
  df1 = df
  return df1
```

#output:

| index | date | Condition | new_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2015-01-20 00:00:00 | 1 | NaT |
| 1 | 2015-02-20 00:00:00 | 1 | NaT |
| 2 | 2015-03-20 00:00:00 | 2 | 2015-03-22 00:00:00 |
| 3 | 2015-04-20 00:00:00 | 2 | 2015-04-22 00:00:00 |
| 4 | 2015-05-20 00:00:00 | 2 | 2015-05-22 00:00:00 |
| 5 | 2015-06-20 00:00:00 | 1 | NaT |
| 6 | 2015-07-20 00:00:00 | 1 | NaT |
| 7 | 2015-08-20 00:00:00 | 2 | 2015-08-22 00:00:00 |
| 8 | 2015-09-20 00:00:00 | 2 | 2015-09-22 00:00:00 |
| 9 | 2015-09-20 00:00:00 | 1 | NaT |

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Is there a way to make sure the new_date column is only populated when '2' condition appears 3 or more times in a row?

Comment: Hum, sorry I didn't understand like this. I'm gonna delete the answer meanwhile somebody else or I found another solution.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is a little bit different. If condition is 1 put None, otherwise I add condition value -1 to the date

```
df['date_new'] = np.where(df['condition'] == 1, None, (df['date'] + pd.to_timedelta(df['condition']-1,'d')).dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y') )
```